# Thoughtbot Clearance -> Why do I always get signed_out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clearance

I am using Clearance gem. It's "half" working.

I can do all basic actions (sign up, sign in, :authorize).

But, when I do a POST action to a controller, it just signs me out ...

Here what's in the log :

```
Started POST "/monkeys" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Jun 03 06:22:00 -0400 2011
  Processing by MonkeysController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Save monkey", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "utf8"=>"\342\234\223", "monkey"=>{"name"=>"fghfgh", "description"=>"fghfgh"}}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`remember_token` = 'c1f450a81fde65282e73ce41f69095b66d782e34' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  AREL (0.3ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `remember_token` = 'b9c2cac3d446bee370e40619c6c8cd42c457bb13', `updated_at` = '2011-06-03 10:22:00' WHERE `users`.`id` = 4
  SQL (1.1ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/sign_in
```

When that happens, I am actually signed in.. what might I have missed?

Thanks

Comment: Oh and by the way, if I remove the :authorize for my POST action, the "current_user" is nil.

Comment: 3.0.5 -- But I found the problem! It was actually because of my cookie domain, for some reason, localhost is not right. So i added a simple dns called "monkey.local" on my machine, and now I access the application with it and all works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually because of my cookie domain, for some reason, localhost is not right. So i added a simple dns called "monkey.local" on my machine, and now I access the application with it and all works fine.

I also believe I can use 127.0.0.0 and it would work. I'll try it at home.